# PHP code for checking Fan page like sometimes work sometimes don't

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

I'm have script below to check whether user is my fan page or not. If yes, they will be redirected to another page. If not, they will be show a like box to like the page before proceed.

The script sometimes work but sometimes don't. I expect this to have issue with header() because it got 500 internal server error. However, i already put ob_start(). Shouldn't that solve the problem?

```
<?
ob_start();
require_once('../../src/facebook.php');

$app_id = "APP_ID";
$app_secret = "APP_SECRET";

// Init facebook api.
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => $app_id,
    'secret' => $app_secret,
    'cookie' => false,
));

//Facebook Authentication part
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();
    $loginUrl   = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
        array(
            'scope'         => 'publish_stream, user_likes'
        )
);

if (!$user_id) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
    exit;
}

$likes = $facebook->api("/me/likes/PAGE_ID");
if( !empty($likes['data']) ){
    ob_end_clean();
    header ('location: xyz.php');      //if is a fan, redirect to xyz.php
    exit;
} else {
    continue;                          //if not a fan, show below html code
}

?>

<HTML>
.
.
Please like page first
.
.
</HTML>
```

Comment: _“because it got 500 internal server error”_ – then check you server’s error logs to see what’s the _actual_ reason.

Comment: The error log shows 'request failed: error reading the headers'. However, this is only came from 1 IP address, which is not me.

Comment: `Location: xyz.php` is not a valid location header – it requires a __full__ URL _by definition_.

Comment: Already changed to full URL. However, didnt work. I still got the error.

Comment: @CBroe Didn't see your comment, which was basically the contents of my answer (I linked to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250393/to-understand-phps-header) too) so I'm deleting my answer in favour of your comment.